# How to check if a composable is on top of the back stack or not?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have a navigation graph containing a `HomeScreen` and a `MyBottomSheet`. For bottom sheets I am using Accompanist Navigation.
Both of the destinations share a common ViewModel which is scoped to that navigation graph. From that ViewModel I am exposing a `Flow<MyEvent>` where `MyEvent` is:

```kotlin
sealed interface MyEvent
object MyEvent1: MyEvent
object MyEvent2: MyEvent
```

The two composables look like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.eventsFlow.collect {
            if(it is Event1) {
                handleEvent1()
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

@Composable
fun MyBottomSheet(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        viewModel.eventsFlow.collect {
            if(it is Event2) {
                handleEvent2()
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that I want `HomeScreen` to handle `Event1` and `MyBottomSheet` to handle `Event2` (these events are basically navigation events).

The problem is that when `MyBottomSheet` is visible, both the composables are collecting the flow at the same time because of which `Event2` also gets collected by `HomeScreen`. What I want is that when `MyBottomSheet` is the topmost destination in back stack, `HomeScreen` shouldn't be collecting flow. One of the possible solutions in my mind is:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    LaunchedEffect(isHomeScreenOnTheTopOfBackStack) {
        if(isHomeScreenOnTheTopOfBackStack) {
            viewModel.eventsFlow.collect {
                if(it is Event1) {
                    handleEvent1()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now here, how can I check if `HomeScreen` is on top of the back stack or not?

Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out it was quite easy. We can use `navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()` in the nav graph and pass the Boolean to the `HomeScreen`.

```kotlin
composable("home") {
    val isOnTop = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.destination?.route == "home"
    HomeScreen(
        viewModel = //,
        isHomeScreenOnTheTopOfBackStack = isOnTop
    )
}
```